# Is it possible to use data annotations for LabelFor,ValidationMessageFor, EditorFor with strongly typed resources?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations

I would like to use DataAnnotations in my ASP.NET MVC application. I have strongly typed resources class and would like to define in my view models:

```
[DisplayName(CTRes.UserName)]
string Username;
```

`CTRes` is my resource, automatically generated class. Above definition is not allowed. Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attributes can't do this

see [C# attribute text from resource file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150874/c-attribute-text-from-resource-file)

Resource.ResourceName would be a string property, attribute parameters can only be constants, enums, typeofs

Answer (score 7):

There's the [DisplayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute(VS.100).aspx) that has been added in .NET 4.0 which allows you to  specify a resource string:

```
[Display(Name = "UsernameField")]
string Username;
```

If you can't use .NET 4.0 yet you may write your own attribute:

```
public class DisplayAttribute : DisplayNameAttribute
{
    public DisplayAttribute(Type resourceManagerProvider, string resourceKey)
        : base(LookupResource(resourceManagerProvider, resourceKey))
    {
    }

    private static string LookupResource(Type resourceManagerProvider, string resourceKey)
    {
        var properties = resourceManagerProvider.GetProperties(
            BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        foreach (var staticProperty in properties)
        {
            if (staticProperty.PropertyType == typeof(ResourceManager))
            {
                var resourceManager = (ResourceManager)staticProperty
                    .GetValue(null, null);
                return resourceManager.GetString(resourceKey);
            }
        }
        return resourceKey;
    }
}
```

which you could use like this:

```
[Display(typeof(Resources.Resource), "UsernameField"),
string Username { get; set; }
```

Comment: That doesn't allow to use **strongly** typed resources. DisplayNameAttribute was bad example, because it doesn't allow using weakly typed too:) My question is not about DisplayName not allowing to use resources, because, as you answered, this can be easily managed. My question is about using them **strongly typed** and not only with this attribute, but with every attribute in DataAnnotations.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer to the question "Are there any other solutions?". The current accepted answer is simply "No you can't"

Answer (score 0):

This now works as it should in MVC3, as mentioned on [ScottGu's post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/27/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx), and would allow you to use the built in DisplayAttribute with a localized resource file.

Comment: :) That is not what I need. When I wrote this question, I didn't notice that DisplayName attribute doesn't take any resources. What I really want to use is **strongly** (`ResourceClass.ResourceName`) typed resouces with all attributes.