# Why I can't use DisplayAttribute with Global Resource file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources

The question already explains what I'm trying to do, here is an example:

```
[Display(Name = Localization.City)]
public string City { get; set; }
```

The error is, but (for me) doesn't make sense: *An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to use DisplayAttribute with resources you need to use

```
[Display(ResourceType=typeof(Localization), Name="City")]
public string City {get;set;}
```

And don't forget to open resource file and set access modifier to public instead of internal.

Comment: This is not working with GridView and AutoGenerateColumns. The Columns names are showing properties names. Any Clue? And yes my resource is public

Comment: Are you talking about WinForms GridView? As far as I know it uses TypeDescriptor.GetProperties that does not respect DisplayName attribute. You may create your custom type descriptor and get display name from the attribute.

Comment: @STO, I have a class which i added Display annotation from resources and i used GetAttributeFrom method from [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027613/how-to-retrieve-data-annotations-from-code-programmatically) to retrieve data of the property but it doesn't show the localized one!

Answer (score 1):

Attribute paramters must be fixed at compile time.
Refer to Jon Skeet's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763981/an-attribute-argument-must-be-a-constant-expression) on SO:

> An expression E is an attribute-argument-expression if all of the
>   following statements are > true: •The type of E is an attribute
>   parameter type (§17.1.3). •At compile-time, the value of E can be
>   resolved to one of the following: •A constant value. •A System.Type
>   object. •A one-dimensional array of attribute-argument-expressions.

Can you show how you have declared 'Localization.City'?

Answer (score 1):

Poached from: [C# attribute text from resource file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150874/c-sharp-attribute-text-from-resource-file)

```
public class CustomAttribute : Attribute
{

    public CustomAttribute(Type resourceType, string resourceName)
    {
                Message = ResourceHelper.GetResourceLookup(resourceType, resourceName);
    }

    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class ResourceHelper
{
    public static  string GetResourceLookup(Type resourceType, string resourceName)
    {
        if ((resourceType != null) && (resourceName != null))
        {
                PropertyInfo property = resourceType.GetProperty(resourceName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
                if (property == null)
                {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Resource Type Does Not Have Property"));
                }
                if (property.PropertyType != typeof(string))
                {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Resource Property is Not String Type"));
                }
                return (string)property.GetValue(null, null);
        }
        return null; 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear.

`Localization.City` is not constant. I assume that it is just a `static` 'read-only' field/property.

Comment: I Agree! I just doesn't understand why the framework is throwing this error. What's the problem with static property?