# c# string arguments in attributes

Tags: c#, attributes, webget

Is it possible somehow to move out the string value declaration in an attribute usage?

Specifically I have:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/myResource/{id}")]
```

But I would rather have something like:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = AStaticDictionaryOrSomething["myResource"])]
```

The reason is that I want to avoid duplicating the uri values without having to do reflection on the class with the WebGet attribute. So the easiest way I think would be to declare the uri values in a single place, and refer to that from the attribute declaration and from elsewhere.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150874/c-sharp-attribute-text-from-resource-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the strings you need as constants in a new class or somewhere and use those as attribute arguments

```
public class ResourceLibrary
{
     public const string MyResource  = "/myResource/{id}";
}
```

And use it like this:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = ResourceLibrary.MyResource)]
```